# How can I query a zip file in gatsby from a markdown file?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, markdown, gatsby

I am using gatsby to create the static pages of my website, and I have my content in markdown files. I want to include the path to a zip file in markdown and query it using graphql to pass it to my React component.

I have tried passing the path to the zip file, and also a string to the path to the zip file.

example.md

```
---
zip: /location/to/zipfile.zip // have also tried '/location/to/zipfile.zip
---
```

component.jsx

```
// some code

// GraphQL query
export const ExampleQuery = graphql`
  query ExampleQuery($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: {eq: $path } }) {
      frontmatter {
        zip
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I get the following error

```
error GraphQL Error Field "zip" of type "File" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "zip { ... }"?
```

I know I can also import the zip file directly in react, but I am avoiding that since I want to query different zip files and pass them down a component based on user selection.